# How does cold water sterilizing work

Tags: sterilization

I am trying to find a description of how the milton method works, but can't find a description online.

It doesn't require rinsing after, does the chemical break down after?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require some degree of prior research when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: Specifically, you might want to have a look at the FAQ for one of the products. https://www.milton-tm.com/en/consumer/faqs